# Can I install rtlinux?

Tags: software-installation, realtime

How do I install rtlinux in Ubuntu? If I get it to install will it make software work abnormally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RealTime , [...]The -preempt and -rt kernels are no longer being developed due to lack of support[...]

I've come across some posts on Ubuntu forums (dated 2008), that mentioned the packages for a rtlinux were on the repos however i have looked them for you and they are no longer available. Seems like the last version that had them on the repos was 10.04.

For installation on 10.04:

On Synaptic search for "rt Linux" then pick the following package

```
linux-r
```

It will install the following packages:

- linux-image-rt
- linux-headers-rt
- linux-rt
- linux-image-2.6.31-10-rt
- linux-rt-headers-2.6.31-10
- linux-headers-2.6.31-10-rt

Then just restart, on GRUB pick  kernel 2.6.31-10-rt and you're done.

Comment: I have succeed install linux-rt,but rt seems not stable than linux-realtime. How to install linux-realtime? Thank you~